# LINQ group by List<results> and return results

Tags: c#, linq

I have Three `List<Results>`

```
var list1 = new List<Results> {
    new Results{ Empid = 1,Empname = "John",Rating = 1.33},
    new Results{ Empid = 2,Empname = "Aarya",Rating = 1.6},
    new Results{ Empid = 3,Empname = "Sansa",Rating = 1.6}
};

var list2 = new List<Results> {
    new Results{ Empid = 1,Empname = "John",Rating = 2.33},
    new Results{ Empid = 2,Empname = "Aarya",Rating = 2.6},
    new Results{ Empid = 3,Empname = "Sansa",Rating = 1.6}
};

var list3 = new List<Results> {
    new Results{ Empid = 1,Empname = "John",Rating = 0.33},
    new Results{ Empid = 2,Empname = "Aarya",Rating = 0.6}
};
```

I want final result like(sum of all ratings based on Empid)

```
Final={Empid=1,Empname="John",Rating=3.99}
  {Empid=2,Empname="Aarya",Rating=4.8}
  {Empid=3,Empname="Sansa",Rating=3.2}
```

How to achieve this by using Linq, I am new to LinQ i am trying using GroupBy but I couldn't.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data as valid C# code?

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for your response.

Comment: Pro tip: whenever you find yourself writing "I tried this but I couldn't", stop, don't write that, **and instead, show us what you have tried**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) to merge the lists and then a normal group by:

```
var result = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3)
                  .GroupBy(item => new { item.Empid, item.Empname }, item => item.Rating)
                  .Select(g => new { 
                      Id = g.Key.Empid, 
                      Name = g.Key.Empname, 
                      Rating = g.Sum() });
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var result = from item in list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3)
             group item.Rating by new { item.Empid, item.Empname } into g
             select new {
                 Id = g.Key.Empid,
                 Name = g.Key.Empname,
                 Rating = g.Sum()
             };
```

*sum of all ratings based on `Empid`* - Note that if the id and name correlate then it is simplest to group by the two of them as in the example above. Otherwise, group by id and retrieve for each group the `.First().Empname`

Answer (score 0):

first you should concat all lists together and then write something like this:

```
var q = from p in concatlist
        group p by new { p.Empid, p.Empname} into g
        select new 
        {
           Empid = g.Key.Empid,
           Empname = g.Key.Empname,
           Rating = g.Sum(c=>c.Rating)
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [Enumerable.SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) method to "flatten" lists and then use same grouping as in other answers

```
var final = 
    new[] { list1, list2, list3 }.SelectMany(list => list)
                                 .GroupBy(result => new { result.EmpId, result.EmpName })
                                 .Select(group => new Results
                                 { 
                                     EmpId = group.Key.EmpId, 
                                     EmpName = group.Key.EmpName, 
                                     Rating = group.Sum(result => result.Rating) 
                                 });
```

With `SelectMany` you will be able to query dynamic amount of lists